# Remove view name from Eclipse menu Window -> Show View

Tags: eclipse, plugins, view

I need to remove the name/shortcut of the view which I have created from the Window->Show View menu and add them as a separate menu.

Is there any way to hide/remove its entry from Window->Show View menu.

Comment: Just added a first clue, for doing the same thing programmatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681622/how-to-remove-views-from-windows-show-view-list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add/remove any view from the "Show View" menu from the Customize Perspective / Menu Visibility tab:

[image: http://img8.i_mageshack.us/img8/3854/menuvisibility.png]

---

To do the same thing programmatically would imply to follow the same course of action than the class [`org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.CustomizePerspectiveDialog`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/dialogs/CustomizePerspectiveDialog.java.htm), and look into the method `okPressed()` for instance:

```
perspective.setShowViewActionIds(menu.getCheckedItemIds());
```

---

[Vlad Ilie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2656234/vlad-ilie)  mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768411/remove-view-name-from-eclipse-menu-window-show-view/1768930?noredirect=1#comment38780824_1768930):

> as I only needed for the `View` to be completely inaccessible via usual GUI, activities were enough for me as per this blog post "[eEclipse Activities – Hide / Display certain UI elements](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/)":
>
> This would mean that programmatically the  `WorkbenchActivitySupport.setEnabledActivityIds(String[])` method can be used to enable or disable views after they've been introduced into an activity.

Comment: Hi VonC,
Thanks for your quick reply.

Can we do it programmatically?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using internal classes?

Comment: @VladIlie 5 years later, I wouldn't know on the top of my head.

Comment: @VonC worth a try, no? :) I will let you know if I find something.

Comment: @VladIlie it does worth a try indeed. I am looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: well, as I only needed for the View to be completely inaccessible via usual GUI, activities were enough for me as per this link: http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/ ... This would mean that programatically the IWorkbenchActivitySupport.setEnabledActivityIds(String[]) method can be used to enable or disable views after they've been introduced into an activity. (this is a long comment)

Comment: @VladIlie that looks promising. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go to window->Preferences or customize perspective. I think this is place from where we can controls the menu's to be displayed.

Comment: Hi Samra,
Thanks for your quick reply.

Actually I need to do it programmatically.

I have created my own menu by creating new extension point 'org.eclipse.ui.menus' and placed commands in it by creating extension points of 'org.eclipse.ui.commands'. The handler classes for each of these commands is given by creating extension points in 'org.eclipse.ui.handlers'.