# How to remove views from Windows-->Show View list?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have view which I am setting permanently on my perspective.
This view can not be closed and can not be opened from Windows --> show views

I struct to remove View from Windows --> view list.

How would I achieve this?

I tried your solution it is doing the things but it is also removing the view from perspective. Below are the steps I followed..

I have added the following view in plugin.XML

```xml
<view
     allowMultiple="false"
     category="org.view.ui.IDECategory"
     class="org.view.ui.BannerInformationView"    
     id="org.view.ui.BannerInformationView"
     name="BannerInfo"
     restorable="true">
</view>
```

After this I have added this view in my Perspective

```java
public void defineLayout( IPageLayout layout )
    {
        layout.setEditorAreaVisible( true );
        layout.addStandaloneView( BANNER_INFO_VIEW_ID, false, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.03f, layout.getEditorArea() );
        IViewLayout viewLayout = layout.getViewLayout( BANNER_INFO_VIEW_ID );
        viewLayout.setMoveable( false );
    }
```

Now I have added the activity to hide my view name from show view menu

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
     <activity
           id="activity.ide"
           name="ide">
     </activity>
     <activityPatternBinding
           activityId="activity.ide"
           isEqualityPattern="true"
           pattern="org.view.ui.IDECategory.pluginid/org.view.ui.BannerInformationView">
     </activityPatternBinding>
  </extension>
```

Now my problem is, along with hiding the view entry from window -> show view, it is also hiding the view from my perspective.

I want to hide the only entry from show view so that user can not do anything with it, but it should be always visible in my perspective.

Comment: You could hide `Window > Show View` altogether using an activity, that way you would not have to filter on the view id.

Comment: @greg-449 My use case is, I have inserted `BannerInformationView` to display some information and It should be there in defined perspective irrespective of the other views. But for other views user can show or close views as usual.

Comment: You can call `setCloseable(false)` on the `IViewLayout` to stop the view being closed. I doesn't look like there is any way to restrict the activity filtering to just the Show View.

Comment: Yes I did the same for restricting user to close the view. But this view should not be added from Show views. So that it will come up with different location.

Answer (score 3):

The view list is filtered by the [activities](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm) list. So you can define an activity to suppress the view:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">  
  <activity id="activity.id" name="Name">
  </activity>
  <activityPatternBinding
     activityId="activity.id"
     isEqualityPattern="true"
     pattern="plugin.id/view.id">
  </activityPatternBinding>
 </extension>
```

Note: The `pattern` value is 'contributing plugin id / view id', a common mistake is leaving out the plugin id.

Comment: Does it remove view also from the perspective?

Comment: If you have specifically added the view to the perspective I think it will still be in the perspective.

Comment: I have modified question can you please have a look.