# Remove "General Project" option: eclipse RCP3

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am developing a GUI in eclipse with RCP3.  Included in the new project options is a "General Project" option that has no relevance to the purpose of my application, and I would like to remove it.  However, I can't find it anywhere in the code of the project.  I suspect that it is included in the core functionality of my imported packages, specifically org.eclipse.ui, but I am not sure.  If anyone would like more information on files such as the manifest or plugin.xml let me know please.

Comment: Look at using the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to define an activity that suppresses the option.

Comment: thanks, this put me on the right track, but i'm having some trouble finding the correct menu item ID.  Do you know what it is, or where to find it?  The search field for the plug in registry is not very effective.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681622/how-to-remove-views-from-windows-show-view-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The New menu options are filtered by the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point activities. So you can suppress entries by defining a suitable activity.

The New General Project entry is defined in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin and has the id `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.new.project`, so an activity to suppress it would be:

```xml
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
    <activity
         id="test.disable"
         name="Disable New Project">
   </activity>
   <activityPatternBinding
         activityId="test.disable"
         isEqualityPattern="true"
         pattern="org.eclipse.ui.ide/org.eclipse.ui.wizards.new.project">
   </activityPatternBinding>
</extension>
```

Note that the `pattern` value includes the plugin id and the item id. This is an equality pattern so it is not a regular expression.

Some more information on activities [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/)

Comment: @greg-449 please have a look at a [slightly-related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38963427/1371217) if you have a chance, thanks!